# "Перезатирание" сообщений в CDC

Tags: ydb

По CDC: если запись дважды была изменена и ни разу не прочитана, то в топике будут обе версии или более свежая "перезатрёт" старую?

Answer (score 0):

В CDC будут отправлены оба изменения: в топик пишется событие при каждом изменении.
Считана запись или нет - не имеет значения.

В [гарантиях](https://ydb.tech/ru/docs/concepts/cdc#guarantees) прописано что на каждое изменение/добавление/удаление записи в таблице будет ровно одно CDC-событие.